# Symfony/Doctrine: does model_object->save() filter value? (Prevent SQL injection)

Tags: doctrine, sql-injection, symfony-1.4

I understand that Doctrine helps against SQL injection attacks. Does the `model_object->save()` command automatically escape unwanted characters, or do I have to write a custom input filter? Thanks.

Comment: This question has just come up for me as well. I'm 95% sure it does, but I can't find confirmation of it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the exact answer to your question can be found in Doctrine manual [implicit-validation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/component-overview/en#validator%3avalid-or-not-valid%3aimplicit-validation).

More info can also be found there: [Validator](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/component-overview/en#validator) and [Data Validation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/data-validation/en).

Regards.